# CSS keep height, crop width in a div

Tags: html, css

I have been searching for a while, I still cannot find the exact answer.
I have a `<div>` for which the width takes 100% of the screen, the height is fixed at 600px.
I would like to add a background picture to the div for which the picture height would fit the `<div>` height (600px and no picture crop). Whenever I modify the width of the screen, the height should always remain 600px. The picture would then be centered and cropped on the width direction.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/268415/pexels-photo-268415.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried

```
`
    background-image: url('your-image.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center; 

    `
```

Comment: It almost works. The only problem is that it also crop the height of the picture. for example if the picture is 700px, it will crop 100px from the picture. BTW to define the height of the div, I am using min-height: 600px;

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you are looking for :

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 600px;
  background: url('https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/704532.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 600px;
  float: left;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  test
</div>
```

Hope this was helpful for you.